# Error when trying to couchapp push code that I updated from team's Git repo

Tags: couchdb, couchapp

> [CRITICAL] nothing to repeat

The above is the error that I get when I tried to push the code in my couchDB. It was all working well until I tried to pull changes from Git repository that our team uses. Haven't resolved it yet.

Any idea(s) or help will be appreciated!

Detailed Error Report is below (for additional info.):

```
thoughtboard$ couchapp push http://localhost:5984/thoughtboard_db
2011-07-04 14:52:52 [CRITICAL] nothing to repeat

    $ couchapp push http://localhost:5984/thoughtboard_db
    2011-07-04 14:52:52 [CRITICAL] nothing to repeat

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/couchapp/dispatch.py", line 48, in dispatch
        return _dispatch(args)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/couchapp/dispatch.py", line 92, in _dispatch
        return fun(conf, conf.app_dir, *args, **opts)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/couchapp/commands.py", line 79, in push
        doc.push(dbs, noatomic, browse, force)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/couchapp/localdoc.py", line 122, in push
        doc = self.doc(db, force=force)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/couchapp/localdoc.py", line 185, in doc
        self._doc.update(self.dir_to_fields(self.docdir, manifest=manifest))
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/couchapp/localdoc.py", line 303, in dir_to_fields
        elif self.check_ignore(name):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/couchapp/localdoc.py", line 285, in check_ignore
        match = re.match(i, item)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/re.py", line 137, in match
        return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/re.py", line 245, in _compile
        raise error, v # invalid expression
    error: nothing to repeat
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what is wrong (I will ask Benoit if I see him on IRC). Perhaps a workaround?

Create a `.couchapprc` instead. It is a standard JSON object.

```
cat > .couchapprc
{ "env":
  { "dev"    : {"db": "http://localhost:5984/thoughtboard_db"}
  , "staging": {"db": "http://user:pass@staging.server:5984/thoughtboard_db"}
  }
}
```

Now simply push with `couchapp push dev`.

Standard practice is **do not** check this file into Git because it has (or might have in the future) production passwords. In fact, tell git to ignore it.

```
echo .couchapprc >> .gitignore
git add .gitignore
git commit -m "Ignore the .couchapprc"
```

If you are concerned about leaving passwords in (git ignored) files on your system, consider that your shell commands (with any passwords) are already stored in `$HOME/.bash_history` and that passwords entered at the command-line are world-readable by typing `ps` when couchapp is running. (This may not be relevant in your situation, just reminding you.)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @jhs!

Adding default or dev environments was not of any avail for me. Though, I got a different error message this time when I followed your instruction (added just the dev environemnt alone in the .couchapprc)

```
$ couchapp push dev .
2011-07-05 20:51:54 [CRITICAL] {'msg': '', 'status_int': 400, 'response': <couchapp.client.CouchdbResponse object at 0xa2ead6c>}

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/couchapp/dispatch.py", line 48, in dispatch
    return _dispatch(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/couchapp/dispatch.py", line 92, in _dispatch
    return fun(conf, conf.app_dir, *args, **opts)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/couchapp/commands.py", line 76, in push
    dbs = conf.get_dbs(dest)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/couchapp/config.py", line 144, in get_dbs
    return [Database(dburl) for dburl in dburls]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/couchapp/client.py", line 223, in __init__
    self.res.head()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/couchapp/restkit/resource.py", line 121, in head
    params_dict=params_dict, **params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/couchapp/client.py", line 141, in request
    raise RequestFailed(str(e))
RequestFailed: {'msg': '', 'status_int': 400, 'response': <couchapp.client.CouchdbResponse object at 0xa2ead6c>}
```